# Jailbroken iPhone - root privileges

Tags: iphone, xcode

I would like to make an app that will manage some files on jailbroken devices like SMS, Notes .db, but I have problems with accessing such files. I've also made just to test my skills, similar application like your file manager and I could browse almost whole file system and access everything except some folders in /var/mobile/Library/. I get a list of contents of /var/mobile/Library but I get nothing in subdirectories like /var/mobile/Library/Notes/, /var/mobile/Library/SBSettings/, and btw what is most important in my case: /var/mobile/Library/SMS/ or /Notes/ displays nothing.
Of course when I browse my device by SSH using Fugu I got everything and have access to everything (like chmod i.e.)

I would be great if you please give me some advices or source code what should I do to have, I guess the root's privileges, not only to access those files, but also change their permissions and names.
I know how to make such operations using typically NSFileManager, but not on files from the directories above like /.../SMS/.

I've never developed an application that strictly need jailbroken device to perform the given tasks. I believe I will need some extra libraries? Is it true? Can I use Xcode or there is something else to develop such apps.

I would be very grateful!

Comment: hello kris. i am also trying to access the /private/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db. but when i provide this path to sqlite3_open, it always gives the error "unable to open database file" but when i access /private/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db, the database opens perfectly. Can u please tell me how did u solve this problem? what did u use to access sms.db? it would be a great help. thnx

Answer (score 2):

Even when jailbroken, applications installed via Xcode or the App Store are still sandboxed. To get read-only access to the entire filesystem, an application has to be installed in `/Applications/` instead of `/var/mobile/Applications/`. To get write access to the entire filesystem, the application would additionally have to be owned by `root` and be flagged with the `setuid` mode

Comment: Yes, but I'm not ging to distribute it in App Store but in Cydia only. So what do I have to do to make my App be owned by root and in setuid mode?

Comment: Upload your application to /Applications/ and then "chmod 6777 /Applications/YourApp.app/YourApp" and "chown root:admin /Applications/YourApp.app/YourApp" from SSH. Note: very few applications require root; bugs in your application could cause the device to be unbootable without a restore

Comment: Sorry to resurrect this old question, but I've asked a similar one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464332/deploying-ios-apps-to-applications-from-xcode-via-build-phase-script-jailbroke with a +100 bounty.  Is there a way to make XCode automatically deploy to /Applications?  I need gdb for testing.  Thanks for all your help

Comment: Using iOS 5. setuid root is not authorized anymore, even on JB phones.

Comment: Let me rephrase : an application with setuid root will not be launched as root by SpringBoard (SB runs as mobile).  The only way I found to launch an application as root from SpringBoard is to replace the app with a shell script which, in turn, launch the real app.  Booth are setuid root (chmod 6755)  AND the app call setuid(0);setgid(0); from the code.  If you have an easier solution - I am willing to hear from you :-) - Thanks

Comment: Yes, an intermediary mobile-owned binary is required on modern iOS versions (3.2+ perhaps?)