# How to work with SMS in iPhone programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, sms

I need to develop an iPhone app for SMS capability. In this app, I need to append a string to the end of each message, which should not be editable by the user.

My second concern is about the read receipt of the message. Is it possible to have the read receipt in iPhone? If yes, how to do it?

I also want to access the `SMS.db` database in my app.

Are these things possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with the standard API, you can't acces to SMS.db if you want upload an app to the store; when you run your application it's "[sandboxed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_%28computer_security%29)".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if in the case i make my phone jailbroken and dont want to upload it on app store. Any Luck with this...

Comment: Yes, i can't help you..but with a rapid search on google i've found this http://www.hackint0sh.org/f9/55906.htm and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516403/jailbroken-iphone-root-privilages

Comment: thnax again Mat, i found these link before itself , let me have an hit on it.